# Выполнение функции внутри функции

Tags: javascript

После выполнения определенного кода, нужно сразу же сделать следующую (разбить таблицу на страницы). Но почему-то выдаёт ошибку. Как это переписать в рабочее состояние?
Заранее благодарю.

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#table_who_block').unblock();
    $('#table_who').html(data);
    var $table = document.getElementById("who"),
    $table_pag = document.getElementById("table_pag"),
    $n = 5,
    $rowCount = $table.rows.length,
    $firstRow = $table.rows[0].firstElementChild.tagName,
    $hasHead = ($firstRow === "TH"),
    $tr = [],
    $i,$ii,$j = ($hasHead)?1:0,
    $th = ($hasHead?$table.rows[(0)].outerHTML:"");
    var $pageCount = Math.ceil($rowCount / $n);
    if ($pageCount > 1) {
        for ($i = $j,$ii = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++, $ii++)
            $tr[$ii] = $table.rows[$i].outerHTML;
        $table_pag.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<div id='buttons'></div");
        sort(1);
    }

    function sort($p) {
        var $rows = $th,$s = (($n * $p)-$n);
        for ($i = $s; $i < ($s+$n) && $i < $tr.length; $i++)
            $rows += $tr[$i];

        $table.innerHTML = $rows;
        document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = pageButtons($pageCount,$p);
        document.getElementById("id"+$p).setAttribute("class","active");
    }

    function pageButtons($pCount,$cur) {
        var $prevDis = ($cur == 1)?"disabled":"",
            $nextDis = ($cur == $pCount)?"disabled":"",
            $buttons = "<button type='button' style='border: none' value='&lt;' onclick='sort("+($cur - 1)+")' "+$prevDis+"><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i></button>";
        $buttons += "<button type='button' style='border: none' value='&gt;' onclick='sort("+($cur + 1)+")' "+$nextDis+"><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></button>";
        return $buttons;
    }     
},
```

А ошибка в sort'e. Не хочет "дефайнить".

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sort is not defined

Comment: обьявите функцию до ее использования

Comment: Пробовал. Функция работает посредством POST от php файла из вне. Поэтому вызвать ДО не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Скрипт пагинации засунул непосредственно в php файл, который вызывается методом POST.